# Get more details in Azure DevOps post deployment approval mail

Tags: deployment, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, commit, release

I set up a DevOps post-deployment approval system successfully. When the user gets a mail to approve my changes in my project, the summary looks like this:

[Summary screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OL0D.png)

Is there a way to show the commits I made which are getting installed in this version. The idea is to make it easier for the customer to get the newest changes out of this mail.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to show the commits I made which are getting installed
>   in this version.

For this issue , if your release pipeline uses build as the artifact source, then the build version will be displayed in the pending approval email. Clicking build version will jump to the corresponding build page. In this build summary page, you will see the corresponding commits. Then click on this commit to view detailed changes.

[image][image]

If you want to display detailed commit information in the email summary, I am afraid this is currently not supported. The content that can be displayed in the notifications email is designed and cannot be changed. You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) site , which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.